# Showing $X_i$ are independent from the $\pi$ system.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_i$ is a random variable from $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$ to $(E_i,\mathcal{E}_i)$.

**Why we can check $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ are independent random variables in the following way?**

The definition for $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ are independent random variables is the sigma algebra generated by them (i.e. $\sigma(X_i)$) are independent.

So it means $\forall A_i \in \sigma(X_i),P(\cap A_i)=\prod P(A_i)$, which is equivalent to say $\forall B_i \in \mathcal{E}_i,P(\cap X_i^{-1}(B_i))=\prod P(X_i^{-1}(B_i))$.

**One asserts that we if $\forall i, \mathcal{E_i}$ is generated by $\pi_i$, where $\pi_i$ is a $\pi$ system containing $\mathcal{E_i}$, then the above statement is equivalent to $\forall B_i \in \pi_i,P(\cap X_i^{-1}(B_i))=\prod P(X_i^{-1}(B_i))$.**

Why does this assertion hold? I have a theorem

> Let $\pi_1, ...,\pi_n$ be collections of measurable sets on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, each of them is $\pi$ system, $\Omega \in \pi_i$ . Suppose
> \begin{align*}
> P(A_1\cap...\cap\ A_n)=P(A_1)\cdot ... \cdot P(A_n),
> \end{align*}
> for all $A_i \in \pi_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(\pi_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ are independent.

I am confused how to use it here since we are considering $X_i^{-1}(B_i)$ instead of $B_i$?

Comment: Hint: if $\mathcal P$ is a $\pi$-system, then $\{X^{-1}(B) \mid B\in \mathcal P\}$ is a $\pi$-system.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it? I can show your statement but still can not proceed.

Comment: In fact, the main problem is how to show for example, $X_{1}^{-1}(\pi_1)$ is the generating $\pi$ system of $\sigma(X_1)$